# command line batch remove _ from its file name

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have multiple files and would like to rename its file.
For example, I have

> "2014_19_24_english_test.doc"

and to change it to

> "2014 19 24 english test.doc"

Here is what I have done so far:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.hwp') do ren "%%~f" "%%~nf:_= %%~xf"
```

and this is not working.  Any help would be appreciated,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the substring replacement syntax with `for` variables, so you need an interim variable to do that, using delayed expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.hwp') do (
    set "FNAME=%%~nf"
    ren "%%~ff" "!FNAME:_= !%%~xf"
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it out and this is what I did :

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "*.doc"') do set LIST=%%i & set LIST | ren "%%~fi" "%%LIST:_= %%"
```

Hope this helps.