# string replacement in a text file in batch code

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file (summary.yml) with multiple lines and I want to replace some of the lines with some other text. e.g. In line 7 I have "Executed By: abcd" . I want to replace this by "Executed By: %USERNAME% " . Not sure why the below is not working. Any help please.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%cd%\summary.yml) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set Sumvar!vidx!=%%A

)
set Sumvar

set word1=Executed By: %USERNAME%

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%cd%\summary.yml) do (
     set Sumvar7=%!Sumvar7!:!word1!%
    )
```

Comment: You need to set the FOR Variable to an Environmental variable first.  And then do the string substitution correctly.

Comment: Thanks Squashman. Do you mean changing this line? set Sumvar7=%!Sumvar7!:!word1!%. I dont know how to set Variable to an Environmental variable could you please give an example? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You do it in your first FOR /F command!

Comment: I don't get what exactly you need; please provide a sample of summary.yml and state what the desired output is... you might also be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33140447/5047996), which is also about string replacement in a `for /F` loop...

Comment: Here is a sample of summary.yml file 


Status: NA
Last Excecuted On: NA
Executed By: NA

These "NA" values" need to be updated with some values coming from some variables like var1, var2, var3 etc so that at the end my summary .yml will be updated like 

Status: var1
Last Excecuted On: var2
Executed By: var3